# handle multiple radiobuttons from same json and treat them separately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

I fetch from my db multiple modifiergroups, for example, "have gluten", "size", and inside this modifiergroups you can choose an option, for example from "size" => 15oz, 20oz, 30oz.

Example of what I want to do.

[image]

Here is what I got.
[image: e]

**I can't treat size and gluten differently so the user can choose.**

My JSON fetched from db

```
{
"id": "cl9t45hry002xvpr91nppx7rx",
"image": "https://madre-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/logo-madre-cafe-header.svg",
"name": "Especiales Item #1",
"description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
"price": "291",
"available": true,
"menuCategoryId": "cl9t45hqu000tvpr9fjw67ype",
"modifierGroups": [
    {
        "id": "cl9x4v8xr0005vpuax56i2z7r",
        "name": "Size",
        "minSelectionAllowed": null,
        "maxSelectionAllowed": null,
        "isMandatory": true,
        "menuItemId": "cl9t45hry002xvpr91nppx7rx",
        "orderItemId": null,
        "modifiers": [
            {
                "id": "cl9x4wm7l0007vpualwl5zyac",
                "type": "15 oz",
                "mandatorySelected": true,
                "onlyOne": null,
                "multiSelect": null,
                "mandatoryOneMultiSelect": null,
                "modifierGroupId": "cl9x4v8xr0005vpuax56i2z7r"
            },
            {
                "id": "cl9x4uual0003vpuax7rtny7b",
                "type": "20 oz",
                "mandatorySelected": true,
                "onlyOne": null,
                "multiSelect": null,
                "mandatoryOneMultiSelect": null,
                "modifierGroupId": "cl9x4v8xr0005vpuax56i2z7r"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "cl9xm0x2b000hvpuaxzyc7oht",
        "name": "Gluten?",
        "minSelectionAllowed": null,
        "maxSelectionAllowed": null,
        "isMandatory": false,
        "menuItemId": "cl9t45hry002xvpr91nppx7rx",
        "orderItemId": null,
        "modifiers": [
            {
                "id": "cl9xm1l27000jvpuajisqm3hl",
                "type": "Without gluten",
                "mandatorySelected": null,
                "onlyOne": null,
                "multiSelect": null,
                "mandatoryOneMultiSelect": null,
                "modifierGroupId": "cl9xm0x2b000hvpuaxzyc7oht"
            },
            {
                "id": "cl9xm1u8z000lvpuazch4ui1s",
                "type": "With Gluten",
                "mandatorySelected": null,
                "onlyOne": null,
                "multiSelect": null,
                "mandatoryOneMultiSelect": null,
                "modifierGroupId": "cl9xm0x2b000hvpuaxzyc7oht"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

And here is my code

```
{modifierGroups.map((mGroup, index) => {
    let { modifiers } = mGroup;

    return (
      <div key={mGroup.id} className="bg-red-200">
        <label> {mGroup.name}</label>
        <input type="radio" name="modifier" value={modifiers.map((a) => a.type)}  />
        {modifiers.map((m, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={m.key} className="bg-green-200">
              <input
                type="radio"
                id={m.id}
                name="modifier"
                onChange={(e) => setRadioButton({ ...radioButton, items: e.target.value })}
                value={modifiers}
              />
              <button className="ring-1 ring-black h-3 w-3 active:bg-blue-200 focus:bg-slate-600" />
              <label htmlFor={m.id}>{m.type}</label>
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio inputs that are a part of a group [need to share the same `name` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group) - it's how the browser is able to tell which inputs to uncheck when you check one.

Here I'm using the name of the modifier group on the mapped inputs. I've also taken the liberty of breaking down the code into sub-components so that it's easier to read. There is the main component, a `Group` component, and an `Option` component.

The main component maps over the `modifiedGroups` array and returns a `Group` for each object, and the `Group` component maps over each of its modifiers (I've called them `options`) and returns an `Option` for each one.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ config }) {
  
  const [ data, setData ] = useState({});
  
  // Take the name and the value from the clicked
  // input and update the state
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setData(prev => {
      return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    });
  }
  
  // `map` over the modifierGroups array and return
  // a Group component for each object, passing in its
  // name, its modifiers (as "options"), and the handler
  return (
    <section>
      {config.modifierGroups.map(group => {
        return (
          <Group
            key={group.id}
            name={group.name}
            options={group.modifiers}
            handleChange={handleChange}
          />
        );
      })}
    </section>
  );
}

// Accepts the name, options, and handler
function Group({ name, options, handleChange }) {

  // And maps over the options to return an Option
  // component for each one. We pass the group name again,
  // the options, the id, and the handler
  return (
    <fieldset>
      <legend>{name}</legend>
      {options.map(option => {
        return (
          <Option
            key={option.id}
            id={option.id}
            name={name}
            value={option.type}
            handleChange={handleChange}
          />
        );
      })}
    </fieldset>
  );
}

// Accepts the group name, type, value, and the handler,
// and returns a grouped radio input with a label
// When an option is checked the handler is called.
function Option({ id, name, type, value, handleChange }) {
  return (
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      <input
        id={id}
        name={name}
        type="radio"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {value}
    </label>
  );
}

const config={id:"cl9t45hry002xvpr91nppx7rx",image:"https://madre-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/logo-madre-cafe-header.svg",name:"Especiales Item #1",description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",price:"291",available:!0,menuCategoryId:"cl9t45hqu000tvpr9fjw67ype",modifierGroups:[{id:"cl9x4v8xr0005vpuax56i2z7r",name:"Size",minSelectionAllowed:null,maxSelectionAllowed:null,isMandatory:!0,menuItemId:"cl9t45hry002xvpr91nppx7rx",orderItemId:null,modifiers:[{id:"cl9x4wm7l0007vpualwl5zyac",type:"15 oz",mandatorySelected:!0,onlyOne:null,multiSelect:null,mandatoryOneMultiSelect:null,modifierGroupId:"cl9x4v8xr0005vpuax56i2z7r"},{id:"cl9x4uual0003vpuax7rtny7b",type:"20 oz",mandatorySelected:!0,onlyOne:null,multiSelect:null,mandatoryOneMultiSelect:null,modifierGroupId:"cl9x4v8xr0005vpuax56i2z7r"}]},{id:"cl9xm0x2b000hvpuaxzyc7oht",name:"Gluten?",minSelectionAllowed:null,maxSelectionAllowed:null,isMandatory:!1,menuItemId:"cl9t45hry002xvpr91nppx7rx",orderItemId:null,modifiers:[{id:"cl9xm1l27000jvpuajisqm3hl",type:"Without gluten",mandatorySelected:null,onlyOne:null,multiSelect:null,mandatoryOneMultiSelect:null,modifierGroupId:"cl9xm0x2b000hvpuaxzyc7oht"},{id:"cl9xm1u8z000lvpuazch4ui1s",type:"With Gluten",mandatorySelected:null,onlyOne:null,multiSelect:null,mandatoryOneMultiSelect:null,modifierGroupId:"cl9xm0x2b000hvpuaxzyc7oht"}]}]};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example config={config} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
fieldset:not(:first-child) { margin-top: 1em; }
fieldset { font-size: 1.1em; }
fieldset legend { font-size: 1.2em; }
label { display: block; }
label:not(:first-child) { margin-top: 0.25em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Above issue is occurring because same name is used for all the input radio boxes (`modifier`). In Html you can select only one value for the same name radio input. To resolve this issue assign different name to different category  of radio input.

[I have attached stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ezh37g?file=src%2FApp.js)

Updated your code below

```
{modifierGroups.map((mGroup, index) => {
        let { name, modifiers } = mGroup;

        return (
          <div key={mGroup.id} className="bg-red-200">
            <label> {name}</label>
            {modifiers.map((m, i) => {
              return (
                <div key={m.key} className="bg-green-200">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id={m.id}
                    name={`modifier_${name}`} // this line provides unique name for different categories
                    onChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
                    value={modifiers}
                  />
                  <button className="ring-1 ring-black h-3 w-3 active:bg-blue-200 focus:bg-slate-600" />
                  <label htmlFor={m.id}>{m.type}</label>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ncQz.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use check-boxes for "Size" and "Gluten". And radiobuttons for the nested options.